# selenium: 'geckodriver' executable may have wrong permissions

Tags: python, selenium, intellij-idea, geckodriver

My setup:

- MacOS 10.12.3 virtual env.
- I've [installed](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#downloading-selenium-server) selenium via `pip install selenium` (3.3.1).
- I've installed geckodriver via `brew install geckodriver` 0.15.0

Trying to run the following [code](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) in intelliJ IDE:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/opt/geckodriver')
driver.get("https://google.com")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
```

and Exception is thrown from the 4th line (`driver = webdriver...`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/itayb/test/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/opt/geckodriver')
  File "/Users/itayb/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 145, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/itayb/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 86, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable may have wrong permissions. 


Process finished with exit code 1
```

must say that the `executable_path` was added after trying to see some answers [here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path/42260873#42260873).
The bin file (`geckodriver` is excute from command line without any problem).
How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed the path of:

`driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/opt/geckodriver')`

to

`driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')`

(and installed Firefox browser, but I'm not sure if related).

Answer (score 0):

Use permissions according to your need

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/opt/geckodriver
```

refer this link to understand permissions

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-change-file-permissions-with-the-chmod-command-on-linux/